# Name does not exist in the current context but table is listed

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a problem with `Linq`, I have a table called `FavoriteMessage` but whenever I try to query this I get the error,

> The name does not exist in the current context

I can see the table listed so I am not sure what is going on, here is a screenshot

[image]

Comment: maybe the table is in another schema, have you tried that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class WforceContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>{}
```

You need to add DbSet here if it's not done by other means. For your example:

```
public DbSet<FavoriteMessage> FavoriteMessages{ get; set; }
```

FavoriteMessage is the  MODEL of your table and FavoriteMessages is the name of it in your context.

If you lack the model, you 1st need to make model, there is plenty of info on how to do that since it's really essential to learn how to do so :)

Answer (score 0):

just drag and drop this table in your **dbml** file again and build the project.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was with Automapper, i forgot that i was ignoring a field on the type mapping and it was not available on the subsequent query.

Answer (score -1):

I just had to include it on the `data context.`

Comment: Can you please elaborate, I am having the same issue.

Comment: You need to add the model into your data context. I assume you are using Entity Framework

Comment: Oh, the question is relating to the LinqPad application as per the screenshot.  So, in LinqPad, how do you add stuff to your data context.  In code I don't have a problem.  Just LinqPad